# laravel 4.1 Validator Same rule Error

Tags: php, laravel-4

i have an error while i try to Validate 2 password field in my project

this is my controller

```
public function showReg()
{
    return View::make('reg');
}
public function addUser()
{


$uname = Input::get('uname');
$f_name = Input::get('name');
$pass = Input::get('pass');
$pass2 = Input::get('pass2');
$hashed = Hash::make($pass);
$hashed2 = Hash::make($pass2);


$val_uname = Validator::make(
    array('User Name' => $uname),
    array('User Name' => 'required|max:20|min:4')

);
$val_fname = Validator::make(
    array('First Name' => $f_name),
    array('First Name' =>'required|max:20|min:4')
    );
$val_pass = Validator::make(
    array('Password' => $pass),
    array('Password' => 'required|min:6|max:8')

);
$val_pass2 = Validator::make(
    array('Password confimation' => $pass2),
    array('Password confimation' => 'required|min:6|max:8|same:pass')

);



if ($val_uname->fails())
{
    return Redirect::to('reg')->withErrors($val_uname);
}
if ($val_fname->fails()) 
{
    return Redirect::to('reg')->withErrors($val_fname);
}
if ($val_pass->fails()) 
{
    return Redirect::to('reg')->withErrors($val_pass);
}
if ($val_pass2->fails()) 
{
    return Redirect::to('reg')->withErrors($val_pass2);
}



$user_data = new User;
$user_data->uname = $uname;
$user_data->name = $f_name;
$user_data->pass = $hashed;
$user_data->save();

return Redirect::to('sucess');
}


    }
```

and here is my view code

```
        @extends('master')


    @section('main')
    {{--  the Forms to post the information to database to create a user --}}

    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'reg')) }}
    {{  Form::label('uname', 'User Name : ')     }}
    {{  Form::text('uname') }}
    <br>
    {{  Form::label('name', 'First Name : ')     }}
    {{  Form::text('name')  }}
    <br>
    {{  Form::label('pass', 'Password : ')   }}
    {{  Form::Password('pass')  }}
    <br>
    {{  Form::label('pass2', 'Password confirmation : ')     }}
    {{  Form::Password('pass2') }}
    <br>
    {{  Form::submit('Submit')  }}

    {{ Form::close()}}

    {{  $errors->first() }}




    @endsection
```

and my Error the i get

The Password confimation and pass must match.

i dont know where is the wrong section in my code

thanks for @Sam due to his help and support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try following way:

```
...
$uname = Input::get('uname');
$f_name = Input::get('name');
$pass = Input::get('pass');
$pass2 = Input::get('pass_confirmation');
$hashed = Hash::make($pass);
$hashed2 = Hash::make($pass2);
...


$rules = array(
    'uname' => 'required|max:20|min:4',
    'name'  => 'required|max:20|min:4',
    'pass'  => 'required|min:6|max:8|confirmed',
    'pass_confirmation' => 'required|min:6|max:8|same:pass'
);
$v = Validator::make($input, $rules);

if( $v->fails() ) {
    $messages = $v->getMessages()->all();    
}
else {
    //validation passed
}
```

The [Confirmed rule](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-confirmed) ensures that, for a given attribute, a matching attribute_confirmation attribute exists. And change your html for confirm password to:

```
{{  Form::label('pass2', 'Password confirmation : ')     }}
{{  Form::Password('pass_confirmation') }}
```

Comment: What is the `same` validation for?

Comment: @Rohan 'same' is to check 'pass_confirmation'  field same as 'pass' field, i.e. both fields should have same value..

Comment: But we already have a `confirmed` validation for that. Is this just an alternate?

Comment: Why aren't we using Input::all()?  Is there a reason?

Comment: @MatthewJohnson nope, there aint any reason, its just a basic example, above code can be modified to use Input:all() to get all the inputs for the request..

Comment: Good to know.  Still getting the hang of Laravel here!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have different validators for validating different fields. You can do it with a single validator. You're validating Password Confirmation with `same:pass` but there is no field `pass` in the validator.

A less complex version of the code:

```
function addUser()
{
    $uname = Input::get('uname');
    $f_name = Input::get('name');
    $pass = Input::get('pass');
    $pass2 = Input::get('pass2');
    $hashed = Hash::make($pass);
    $hashed2 = Hash::make($pass2);

    $input = array(
            'uname' => $uname,
            'name'  => $f_name,
            'pass'  => $pass,
            'pass2' => $pass2
        );

    $rules = array(
            'uname' => 'required|max:20|min:4',
            'name'  => 'required|max:20|min:4',
            'pass'  => 'required|min:6|max:8',
            'pass2' => 'required|min:6|max:8|same:pass'
        );

    $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('reg')->withErrors($validator);
    }

    $user_data = new User;
    $user_data->uname = $uname;
    $user_data->name = $f_name;
    $user_data->pass = $hashed;
    $user_data->save();

    return Redirect::to('sucess');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer guys and thans for help im on mobile now 20 mnt and I will try the solutions that you provided to me